# How to move Form page during design (VS 2008)

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I apologize for what may be a rudimentary question but I have looked through the net and can not find the answer to this question.

While designing the form in C#, I want to physically move the actual form to a different place on my Design Screen. I am not referring to it's location when I debug and run, but rather its positioning while I am designing it. I can't seem to drag it anywhere, and it seems to be locked in its position.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is that you can't move the form in design mode, it's bound to the upper left corner. However you can undock and resize the window containing the form and move that to wherever you like, like shown in this screenshot:

.[image]

Comment: I see that you've done it in VS2012/13? How would I do that in VS2008?  You've addressed the question perfectly, thank you JPW

Comment: @Pardon_me I don't have access to VS2008, but I would imagine you would do the same thing (grab the tab at the title and drag to undock), but I really don't remember what 2008 looked like (if it even used docked windows.

Comment: I can undock the toolbar and things like that, but I can't seem to find a way to float the Form....